# Check if index of elements in two lists are consecutive

Tags: python, list, for-loop

If list1 is defined as `[15,1,20]`
and list2 is defined as `[6,15,3,1,6,20]`

The function will return True because list 2 contains `(15,1,20)` in the same order.

However if list 2 was defined as `[6,1,15,20,3]`,  the sequence is `(1,15,20)` therefore it will return False.

```
def sublist(lst1,lst2):
    for i in lst1:
        if i in lst2:
            if ## ?? ##
                return True
    return False
```

The if statement is where I am confused because I'm not sure how to check for consecutive numbers in two different lists.

Answer (score 2):

Take a single item from the input list and scan forward over the second list until you have a match, then take the next item, continue forward, etc.

Using iterators, taking the next value to test is simple enough. Create an iterator for `lst1` with [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), and then the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) gives you the next item in the list order. When that call raises `StopIteration` you know you have tested all the values in the first list:

```
def sublist(lst1, lst2):
    source = iter(lst1)
    try:
        item = next(source)
        for value in lst2:
            if item == value:
                item = next(source)
        return False
    except StopIteration:
        # all items in lst1 checked
        return True
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst1 = [15, 1, 20]
>>> sublist(lst1, [6, 15, 3, 1, 6, 20])
True
>>> sublist(lst1, [6, 1, 15, 20, 3])
False
```

Note that the function also returns `True` if `lst1` is empty (the empty list is *always* an ordered subset) and `False` if `lst1` is not empty but `lst2` *is* (an empty list can never be a superset).

Comment: Jesus. I have been writing code on python without any idea that `iter()` existed for a couple years now.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work, based on the [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method's `start` parameter:

```
def sublist(lst1, lst2):
    ind = 0
    for a in lst1:
        try:
            ind = lst2.index(a, ind)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True

>>> sublist([1,2,3], [4,1,3,2,5])
False
>>> sublist([1,2,3], [4,1,2,5,3])
True
```

This iteratively looks up the elements of `lst1` in `lst2` while moving ahead the start index for the lookup appropriately until any element can't be found in the remainder of `lst2` or all are found.

Answer (score 0):

get the index list for each item in the original list in the second list and check if any combination of them are in ascending order

Comment: That'd take multiple scans across the second list; you can do this in a single scan.

Comment: True, but its a lazy solution which should give OP a nudge in the right direction. And it handles for edge cases

Comment: list1 = (15,1,10); list2 = (1,15,1,10)

Comment: I'm not sure how that's an edge case, can you elaborate?

Comment: not an issue in your solution because it inherently handles for it inherently